# Run Python Script Without Dependencies Installed

Tags: python, cross-platform

I am creating a Python application that uses multiple third party libraries. Since the libraries are installed on my computer, the script runs fine. However, how can I alter my script so that it will run on any computer (all major OS), even if the computer does not have the third party Python libraries installed?

Comment: For Windows/Mac, you can use Py2exe/Py2app. For Linux distros, you make packages.

Comment: or pyinstaller for windows :) (thats the one I like :P )

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted. I want the script to stay a python script if at all possible so that it can be run on any device and run through a webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your comment:

> I want the script to stay a python script if at all possible so that
>   it can be run on any device and run through a webpage

It appears you want some way to host a python program online.

To do this, you need:

1. To know how to write Python that serves a website (see [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/), etc...)
2. Some way to deploy said application to the web. An easy, free (<-- this is the keyword) way to deploy Python web apps is through using [Heroku](https://get.heroku.com/) or some other free hosting site. Or you could always pay for hosting or host it yourself.

Comment: Hmm...I suppose this could work. I was originally thinking that my script would be able to be hosted through a webpage and be run locally on any device. But I suppose I can create multiple versions of the program, one for each OS I want to support and one to host through the web page of my site. Thanks.